# Log a full url in varnishncsa

Tags: url, logging, varnish

I have a vernish serving request from large urls like this example:

IP/123456789a123456789b123456789c123456789d123456789f123456789g123456789h123456789i123456789j123456789k123456789l123456789m123456789n123456789o123456789p123456789q123456789r123456789s123456789t123456789u123456789v123456789w123456789x123456789y123456789z123456789a123456789b123456789c123456789d123456789e123456789f123456789g123456789h123456789i123456789j123456789k

But in the log, only a part of them is register:

IP1 - - [21/Mar/2014:12:32:05 +0100] "HEAD 123456789a123456789b123456789c123456789d123456789f123456789g123456789h123456789i123456789j123456789k123456789l123456789m123456789n123456789o123456789p123456789q123456789r123456789s123456789t123456789u123456789v123456789w123456789x123456789y123456789z1234 HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "curl/5.11.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/5.11.0

I look for any configuration options but the info page don't tell any about that:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishncsa.html

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the response from the official [forum](https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/1443), this is the solution for debian systems:

Add in the default configuration file located at "/etc/default/varnish" a line for enlarge the DAEMON_OPTS varibale:

```
-p shm_reclen=1024"
```

Finally, all block will be like this example:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:8080 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m \
         -p shm_reclen=1024"
```